# Aggregate in R based on unique values in column

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df` with three columns `item`, `store` and `week`. It looks like this:

```
 item           store         week
24128          272568         1203
25554          272568         1203
24177          272568         1203
72000          272568         1203
72001          272568         1203
24128          272568         1204
25554          272568         1204
24177          272568         1204
72000          272568         1204
72001          272568         1204
-----          ------         ----
24128          272569         1203
25554          272569         1203
24177          272569         1203
72000          272569         1203
72001          272569         1203
24128          272569         1204
25554          272569         1204
24177          272569         1204
72000          272569         1204
72001          272569         1204
```

I would like to see each `item` exists in how many `store`. I tried the following:

```
aggregate(store~item, data = df,FUN = "length")
```

and the function `summaryBy` in `doBy` package:

```
summaryBy(store~item,data = df,FUN = c(length))
```

But, the function `length` returns number of `store` with double counting, i.e, it counts each `store` for each `week`. How do I avoid this double counting and get unique length of `store` for each `item`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to get the `length` on the `unique` elements

```
aggregate(store~item, data = df,FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))
```

---

Or if we are using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(storen = n_distinct(store))
```